# Push notifications not working with any scope other than "/"

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I am working with push notifications. Does push notifications works, if I register my service worker with scope other than "/".

I tried to implement it, but it's not working. Searched about it, but couldn't find solution.

Here is the code I tried, with "/home" scope.

navigator.serviceWorker.register("/home/sw.js")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code on where you think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your worker is located in the root directory, you can try registering it like below.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {scope: '/home/'})
```

Also you might wanna take a look at MDN's examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register#Examples).